# Estimating the $L^{\infty}$-norm of a Laplacian of a function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, maximum-principle, elliptic-equations

Considering the problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}[c]{11}
\Delta(\Delta \chi -\chi) = 0 & \text{in } \Omega, \\
\Delta \chi -\chi = h_2 - h_1, & \text{on } \partial\Omega \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

where $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $h_1$ and $h_2$ are given functions in $\partial\Omega$.

By Riesz theorem the system admits a unique and regular solution $\chi \in H^2(\Omega)$.

I want to find some estimative for the $\|\Delta \chi\|_{\infty}$ in terms of $\|\chi\|_{\infty}$.

By the Maximum Principle we have
$$\|\Delta\chi - \chi \|_{\infty} = \|h_2 - h_2\|_{\infty}$$
and by the other hand
$$\|\Delta\chi - \chi \|_{\infty} \leq \|\Delta \chi\|_{\infty} + \|\chi\|_{\infty}.$$

I was tryin to argue something like "Then exists some $c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that"
$$c\|\chi\|_{\infty} \geq \|h_2 - h_2\|_{\infty}$$
but I'm stuck on the passage of proving the existence of this constant $c$.(I don't know if this is thruth!!!!)

Another way of thinking is to search an argument to prove that I can estimate $$\|\Delta \chi\|_{\infty} \leq A\|\chi\|_{\infty} $$
for some $A$ depending of some parameters.

The main goal here is to find an estimate of $\|\chi\|_{\infty}$ in terms of $h_1$ and $h_2$.

If anyone have ideas, I'll be grateful!

Comment: Your PDE seems to lack boundary conditions on $\chi$. Indeed it could be written as $\Delta u=0$ with $u=h_2-h_1$ coupled with $\Delta\chi-\chi=u$. This last equation does not have boundary conditions so your assertion about uniqueness of solution seems strange to me. If you make that precise, you might use a maximum principle on this equation to get an estimation on $\chi$ in terms of $u$, and then use your estimation on $u$ in terms of $h_2-h_1$ to conclude.